# Resetting Position of Falling Cube

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working on a project using react-three-fiber where i want to set an infinite falling of meshes.

I redid a small prototype displaying only a falling (upward) red cube here : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-cdn-jv9gvk?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-39%2C1

I'm using useFrame to update the cube's position over time. When the cube's y-position exceeds a threshold, I want to reset its position to start falling again but it only works once and it's position doesn't seem to be resetted in my console.log.

If anyone has ever encountered this kind of issue, any help is appreciated !

Here is the relevant useFrame :

```
useFrame(({ clock }) => {
  if (!cubeRef.current) return;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const time = clock.getElapsedTime();

  cubeRef.current.position.y = time * 100;

  if (cubeRef.current.position.y > height / 2) {
    console.log("too high");
    cubeRef.current.position.y -= height * 2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modulo` to looping this "falling" and repeat in specified range `cubeRef.current.position.y = (time % (height / 100)) * 100;`

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { CustomCanvas } from "./CustomCanvas";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import "./styles.css";

const FallingCube = () => {
  const cubeRef = useRef(null);

  useFrame(({ clock }) => {
    if (!cubeRef.current) return;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    const time = clock.getElapsedTime();

    cubeRef.current.position.y = (time % (height / 100)) * 100;

    if (cubeRef.current.position.y > height / 2) {
      console.log("too high");
    }
  });

  return (
    <mesh ref={cubeRef} scale={100}>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshBasicMaterial color="red" />
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomCanvas>
        <FallingCube />
      </CustomCanvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/musing-napier-xd797v?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A32%2C21